# Swift - Select first item from the collection view programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a problem calling the selectItem method for collection view.
Images from Firebase Storage are loaded into the collection view. After loading the first image I want to invoke programmatically click on the first image.
I tried

```
  self.collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
```

But it doesn't work.
The didSelectItemAt method works correctly when I manually click on the collection view element.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: `self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: .init(item: 1, section: 0))`

Comment: first item is `(0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to select it manually

```
let ind =  IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0) 
self.collectionView.selectItem(at:ind, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally) 
self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt:ind)
```

As `didSelectItemAt` is called only when the user taps the cell

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in CollectionViewWillDisplay function, its a delegate function

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { let ind =  IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) self.collectionView.selectItem(at:ind, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally) self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt:ind) }`

This will call collectionView didSelectItem function

`self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt:ind)`